# Using Lambda functions in CUDA with template functions

Tags: templates, lambda, cuda

I was trying to implement a Generic Class using Cuda for common algorithms like Reduce or Scan providing some pre processing such as a simple map inside the algorithm. This map operations are carried out before the actual reduce/scan algorithm. In order to realize this I was hoping to use the lambda functions. Following is the way I tried to implement this.

```
template<typename T> void __device__ ReduceOperationPerThread(T * d_in, T * d_out, unsigned int size)
{
    //Actual Reduce Algorithm Comes here 
}

template<typename T, typename LAMBDA> 
__global__ void ReduceWithPreprocessing(T * d_in, T * d_out, unsigned int size, LAMBDA lam)
{
    lam();

    ReduceOperationPerThread(d_in, d_out, size);
}
```

The helper function that invokes this kernel is created as follows,

```
template<typename T, typename LAMBDA>
void Reduce(T * d_in, T * d_out, unsigned int size, LAMBDA lam)
{
    // preparing block sizes, grid sizes
    // and additional logic for invoking the kernel goes here
    // with the Kernel invocation as following

    ReduceWithPreprocessing<T><<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_in, d_out, size, lam)
}
```

All of the above code is included in a source named Reduce.cu and the respective header is created as Reduce.h as following

```
// Reduce.h
template<typename T, typename LAMBDA>
void Reduce(T * d_in, T * d_out, unsigned int size, LAMBDA lam);
```

So at the end of the day the complete Reduce.cu looks like this,

```
// Reduce.cu
template<typename T> void __device__ ReduceOperationPerThread(T * d_in, T * d_out, unsigned int size)
{
    //Actual Reduce Algorithm Comes here 
}

template<typename T, typename LAMBDA> 
__global__ void ReduceWithPreprocessing(T * d_in, T * d_out, unsigned int size, LAMBDA lam)
{
    lam();

    ReduceOperationPerThread(d_in, d_out, size);
}

template<typename T, typename LAMBDA>
void ReduceWPreprocessing(T * d_in, T * d_out, unsigned int size, LAMBDA lam)
{
    // preparing block sizes, grid sizes
    // and additional logic for invoking the kernel goes here
    // with the Kernel invocation as following

    ReduceWithPreprocessing<T><<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_in, d_out, size, lam)
}
```

But the problem I'm having is related to writing template functions in separate `.h` and `.cu` files

In normal cases where lambda functions are not used, what I used to do was adding all the possible implementations of the function with possible values for template parameter at the end of the `.cu` file as mentioned in [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl-export-keyword), under FAQ - "How can I avoid linker errors with my template classes?"

```
// At the end of the Reduce.cu file
// Writing functions with possible template values 
// For A normal Reduce function

template void Reduce<double>(double * d_in, double * d_out, unsigned int size);
template void Reduce<float>(float * d_in, float* d_out, unsigned int size);
template void Reduce<int>(int * d_in, int * d_out, unsigned int size);
```

But in this case possible value for template parameter `LAMBDA` cannot be predefined.

```
template void ReduceWPreprocessing<int>(int * d_in, int * d_out, unsigned int size, ??? lambda);
```

Is there another way to use lambda functions for this kind of applications?

Comment: I don't think that model lambda expression usage would even be valid in plain vanilla C++11.  Every lambda expression generates a type, so you would either need to define the type of `LAMBDA` at template instantiation time, or use a supported placeholder mechanism like `std::function` in order to have "anonymous" lambda expressions as template arguments. CUDA doesn't have `std::function` support in device code, so I fail to see how this could be done.

Comment: Is there a way to find the type of a lambda function?

Comment: No. Every lambda expression produces a new, unique, unnamed type. The only guaranteed property is conversion to a function pointer.

Comment: So the bottom line is, we cannot use lambda function alongs with other template parameters?

Comment: In CUDA, I don't think so. In C++11, you have `decltype` which can capture the type of a lambda expression. In CUDA, that isn't supported AFAIK

Comment: Since CUDA 8 there is a way to declare a lambda type like `std::function` for device code. It is `nvstd::function` available in `#include <nvfunctional>`.
Exemple: `typedef nvstd::function<void(float&)> unaryFunction;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Summarizing comments into a community wiki answer to get this question off the unanswered queue]

At the time the question was posted, there was no way to do what the question asked, because CUDA lacked the equivalent of a placeholder mechanism which could capture lambda expressions.

However, CUDA (as of version 8, released Q1 2017) now has a `std::function` like polymorphic function wrapper called [nvfunctional](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#polymorphic-function-wrappers). This will allow you to define a generic type for the lambda expression which can be used as a template parameter during instantiation, and then capture a lambda passed as an argument and call it in a generic fashion.